# F#: Using named tuples in JSON

Tags: json, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first language.

I want to save a tuple of record fields (which I have previously defined) in a JSON file. The end result looks something like this:

```
"Players": {
    "m_Item1": {
        "Player 1": "ABC",
        "Player 2": "DEF",
        }
    },
    "m_Item2": {
        "Player 1": "GHI",
        "Player 2": "JKL",
        }
    }
```

Rather than saving the items of the tuple as "m_Item1" and "m_Item2", I'd like to use names of my own choosing -- e.g., "First Match" and "Second Match".

How may I do so?

EDIT: Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
[<DataContract>]
    type FightSummary = 
        { 
            [<DataMember(Order = 1)>] mutable event: string; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 2)>] mutable winner: string option; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 3)>] mutable loser: string option; 

        }

[<DataContract>]
    type FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight =
        { 
            [<DataMember(Order = 1)>] mutable fighter: string; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 2)>] mutable opponent: string; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 3, Name = "kd")>] mutable knockdowns: int option; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 4, Name = "sigStrPercent")>] mutable sigStrikePercentage: int option; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 5, Name = "tdPercent")>] mutable takedownPercentage: int option
        }

[<DataContract>]
    type FightInfo = 
        { 
            [<DataMember(Order = 1)>] mutable fightSummary: FightSummary; 
            [<DataMember(Order = 2)>] mutable fighterStats: FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight * FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight; 
        }

let internal saveJsonToFile<'t> (someObject:'t) (filePath: string) =   
    use fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate) 
    (new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof<'t>)).WriteObject(fileStream, someObject)
```

FightInfo, when saved in JSON, looks something like this:

```
[{
    "fightSummary": {
        ...
    },
    "fighterStats": {
        "m_Item1": {
            ...
        },
        "m_Item2": {
            ...
        }
    }]
```

Rather than "m_Item1" and "m_Item2", I'd like to use names of my own choosing, e.g., "Fighter1Stats" and "Fighter2Stats".

Comment: can you please show us your F# data-type and the way/framework you are using to convert this into JSON? - aside form that you should be able to just use F# records with the [`CLIMutable`-Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289724.aspx)

Comment: What you call "named tuples" are records. F# doesn't give names to each item in a tuple. So have you tried using records instead?

Comment: @CarstenKönig, I have added relevant code :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you try using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) as it has a nice F# interface and as you'll see in the code, the syntax is more lightweight than data contract serializer. Look at the [copy and update record expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) to avoid the `mutable` unless you absolutely need it.

And finally as for your actual question: **introduce the two fighters are properties on the parent records as opposed to having the pair of them as one property.**

```
open Newtonsoft.Json

type FightSummary = 
    { 
        event: string
        winner: string option
        loser: string option
    }

type FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight =
    { 
        fighter: string
        opponent: string
        [<JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "kd")>] knockdowns: int option
        [<JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "sigStrPercent")>] sigStrikePercentage: int option
        [<JsonPropertyAttribute(PropertyName = "tdPercent")>] takedownPercentage: int option
    }

type FightInfo = 
    { 
        fightSummary: FightSummary
        fighter1Stats: FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight
        fighter2Stats: FighterOverallStatsInASpecificFight
    }


let myFight =
    { fightSummary =
        { event = "MyEvent" 
          winner = None
          loser = None }
      fighter1Stats =
        { fighter = "Hulk"
          opponent = "Hogan"
          knockdowns = None
          sigStrikePercentage = None
          takedownPercentage = None } 
      fighter2Stats =
        { fighter = "Hogan"
          opponent = "Hulk"
          knockdowns = None
          sigStrikePercentage = None
          takedownPercentage = None } }

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myFight)
|> printfn "%s"
```

Comment: Don't forget that JSON.NET will happily put `null` values for properties that aren't present in your JSON. If the type of corresponding record's field is, say, another record, it might lead to segfaults at run time.